# Need to filter out multiple values using aggregation

Tags: java, sql, mongodb, filter, aggregation-framework

I am fetching data from mongodb using aggregation pipeline.
I need to filter out multiple values from db.

sql query is like

```
select * from product where name in ("abc","efg");
```

I am confused on what value needs to be given in place of xxx below.

```
Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("name",xxx);
```

Can someone help on this?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Comment: Used Filters.in instead of Filters.eq and it worked. Thank You!!!